# Looking For an Excellent Resource for People Learning Linguistics

Tags: discussion, resources

Was wondering if anyone knows of a solid resource (site) on the web or even an app in the play store that would be a good place to go to supplement my learning in school...i.e. someplace that has a good amount of the right information plus examples and/or tutorials with answers for things like syllabification, complementary and contrastive distribution, syntax, phonology, etc.

Comment: I'm upvoting this question because it may, indeed, be off-topic but I am interested in such resources as well, and who knows, one day it might be on-topic because things change and if a broader audience shows interest, then, why not?

Comment: Check out the two Intro Ling coursepacks and other resources linked in [my user profile here](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/15299/john-lawler?tab=profile)

Comment: Resource questions generally go on Meta.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [request for resources](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/). Note that the "endorsed resources" question I linked to there is **Closed**, and the associated closure text says it *exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site.*

Comment: The [Linguistics.se] site meta might have some useful stuff.